# Frozen keyword in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

No matter if i use or do not use frozen keyword with UDT, it is updating records.

I have table user:

```
CREATE TABLE demokeyspace.user (
    userid text PRIMARY KEY,
    address1 frozen<address>,
    password text,
    uname text
)
```

and address type:

```
CREATE TYPE demokeyspace.address (
    street text,
    city text,
    zip_code int
);
```

[image: I have inserted 2 records:]

[image: Now when i update record for userid 2:]

**It is updating street:'updated street' and city and zip_code to null**

As per Cassandra, it does not allow update of UDT values if it is declared as FROZEN.

can somebody help me on this ?

Comment: I am using   [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use not-frozen UDT, and want to update one field, then you can use following ([see docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useInsertUDT.html)):

```
update user set address1.street='updated street' where userid='2';
```

In your case, you're updating the full `address1` field with UDT that has only one value inside...

In case if you're using frozen UDT, you **must** to specify all values during update, something like you're doing right now, but providing all values.

Use of frozen values is encouraged if you're always updating the full record, but if you'll need to update parts of the record, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: thanks Alex, just one question , if i have a UDT like List<Order>   and order have 20 columns . what is the maximum size this UDT can have and its feasibility ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `Order` is UDT - in this case, it should be frozen. "Frozen" values are just set of the bytes, so the overall size will be the size of all fields in this UDT + some overhead for representing type.  Regarding `list` - if it's possible (order of values doesn't matter, etc.), then it's better to use `set` instead - it has better representation on disk.

Comment: ok let suppose i have 1000 orders per day, is it suitable to defined it as an UDT in Cassandra ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not completely understand... UDT is used to represent complex data structure. Order usually has it , so it's ok to represent it as UDT. Storing orders in the list - that's another question. Maybe it's more effective to represent every order as separate row, but this really depends on your access patterns...

Comment: frozen<List<address>>  and  List<frozen<address>> are both same ? when i create a column as addressdetail frozen<List<address>> then it appear as addressdetail frozen<list<frozen<address>>> . when i describe the table;

Comment: No - first one is one value - all data is serialized together & put as one cell inside Cassandra. You can't update individual entries inside it. The 2nd one is a list of individual addresses, and each address is serialized separately - you can add/remove/update individual addresses, but also as a whole